# Listening to Request (Get/ Post) from Flash

Tags: java, php, flash, post, get

I realized that some flash application make use of POST and GET.

I think Java is a good option to use to listen to POST / GET.

I have a browser that i plan to use , is there anyway i can listen to the browser's post and get request and send request with/without the browser. I'm not really sure how this can work out and what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Flash works well with Http Services, which offers different kind of requests using HTTP methods such as GET, POST, PUT & DELETE.

There are different ways to create HttpServices using Java. Java based REST frameworks can be used to create Http services. There are frameworks such as Jersey, Resteasy, Restlets etc that can be good choice to implemnet RESTful web services in Java.

Comment: But do I need the flash player to be running the application for me to communicate with it

Comment: @RainbowHat Most likely you should be using actionscript to call these services.

Comment: i tested the app , when i press search in the flash app, it does a POST but i get expired session when i copy paste the link on a browser. So it's still possible to communicate with it using perhaps URLHTTPCONNECTION? without flash